# MongoDb Join Lists in aggregate Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents are like this:

```
{
    "date" : 20200817,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "item1", "values" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "item2", "values" : ["val1", "val3", "val4", "val5"]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "item3", "values" : ["val1", "val3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get intersection (∩) `values` that `items.name` in `["item1", "item2"]` like this

`["val1", "val3"]`

I have this query :

```
db.output.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    output: {
      $map: {
        input: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$lists",
            cond: {$in: ["$$this.name", ["item1", "item2"]]}
          }
        }, in: "$$this.values"
      }
    }
  }
},
  {
    "$project": {
      "output": {"$setUnion": "$output"}
    }
  }])
```

but the result is

```
{
    "output" : [ 
        ["val1", "val2", "val3"], 
        ["val1", "val3", "val4", "val5"]
    ]
}
```

Where is my query wrong?

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$setUnion` inside `$reduce`,

```
db.output.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      output: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$items",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $in: ["$$this.name", ["item1", "item2"]] },
                  "$$this.values",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KMTWLs5VQFc)

---

Your second edited question,

You can try `$setIntersection` in your implemented query, inside second `$project` pipeline stage.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J008XIVqydm)

Comment: thanks for your answer. for get the common values (`["values1", "val3"]`) of list what should i do ?

Comment: i am not getting you, i can not see this in your question, can you explain.

Comment: it was a new question. I want to get common values that `items.name` in `["item1", "item2"]` like this `["val1", "val3"]`

Comment: I want to get intersection (∩) of values

Comment: for my second edited question if i want to get values that `items.name` in `["item1"]` the output return null

Comment: yes but its not possible to do fully dynamic, look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CPCOw1voKNG)